# How to add the text inside the pie chart?

Tags: javascript, pie-chart

I've created the pie chart everything looks great but I can't insert the text inside the each section of the pie chart such as *"data 1"* or *"data 2"*. I know there is the fill text method but in this case, I can't fill the text with x position and y position. Do you have any idea?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

<script>

function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // Colors
  var colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'purple'];


  // store beginning angle and ending angle 
  var beginAngle = 0;
  var endAngle = 0;
  // data input 
  var data =[10,10,10,10,10]
  var total = 0;
  //sum of data
  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    total = total + data[i];

  }
  // Iterate through the angles
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 1) {
    beginAngle= endAngle;//begin angle
    endAngle = endAngle+((Math.PI*2)*(data[i]/total));//end angle

    ctx.beginPath();
    // Fill color
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];

    //create each arc of the pie chart
    ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
    ctx.arc(200, 200, 120, beginAngle,endAngle);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
    ctx.stroke();

    // Fill
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
window.onload = draw;


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have edited your Code. You have to calulate the Position of every Piece with Cosinus(X Axis) and Sinus (Y Axis) and set the text there with the position and the text with cancas.getContext("2d).fillText("text", x, y)

**HTML**

```
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid 
#d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
function draw() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Colors
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'black', 'purple'];


// store beginning angle and ending angle 
var beginAngle = 0;
var endAngle = 0;
// data input 
var data = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
var total = 0;
//sum of data
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    total = total + data[i];

}
// Iterate through the angles
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 1) {
    beginAngle = endAngle; //begin angle
    endAngle = endAngle + ((Math.PI * 2) * (data[i] / total)); //end angle

    ctx.beginPath();
    // Fill color
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];
    //create each arc of the pie chart
    ctx.moveTo(200, 200);
    ctx.arc(200, 200, 120, beginAngle, endAngle);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill()

    // Set Text
    var pieRadius = Math.min(ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2);
    var labelX = ctx.canvas.width / 2 + (pieRadius / 2) * Math.cos(beginAngle + (endAngle - beginAngle) / 2);
    var labelY = ctx.canvas.height / 2 + (pieRadius / 2) * Math.sin(beginAngle + (endAngle - beginAngle) / 2)
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.font = "bold 10px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("test", labelX, labelY);

    // Fill
}
}
draw()
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xh08uoqm/)

But instead using Canvas you can use Highchart
[Pie Diagramm with Highchart](https://codepedia.info/highcharts-asp-net-create-pie-chart-with-jquery-ajax-in-c-sharp-ms-sql-database/)

Comment: wow it works like a charm Thanks i will check HIghChart plugin thanks